# How to create Unix and Linux binaries from Python code

Tags: python, linux, unix, cross-compiling

Anybody know how this can be done?  I took a look at cx_Freeze, but it seems that it doesn't compile everything necessary into one binary (i.e., the python builtins aren't present).

Comment: `cx_Freeze` works fine for me, at least on Windows (never tried on Linux). If the **builtins** were missing, that would be a pretty severe but - I doubt it would stay unnoticed. That being said, if it missing a dependency, you can also explicitly tell it to include it (refer to docs).

Comment: Why would you want this? Just make a deb and rpm if you want to make it easy to install.

Comment: John, what version of python is installed on your os and what version of cx_freeeze does you use?

Comment: Python is included on most all Unix/Unix-like systems, so I don't see the use of this...

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: Not always in necessary version. RHEL has ancient versions of python.

Comment: @Rafe & @adw I don't want anyone to peek through my code. ;) @osgx Haven't actually tried cx_freeze out, just was looking at it as a possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard freeze tool (from Tools/freeze) can be used to make fully-standalone binaries on Unix, including all extension modules and builtins (and omitting anything that is not directly or indirectly imported).

Comment: Had no clue about that. Thanks so much, it sounds like exactly what I need.